# How to make a RPG (Rocket Propelled Grenade)

Tags: building, star-wars, city

I don't know if this is of-topic or anything, but: I have a big scene with cops and stormtroopers fighting. And the cops need some stronger weapons than some [sub-machine guns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FZVTDCY). So i was wondering if there were some people out there who had done anything similar. Does anyone have some RPG or anti-aircraft gun/big turret gun ideas?

Comment: Check out the gun on one of the train cars of the Lone Ranger Constitution Chase set. That should do. You can download building instructions from lego.com

Answer (score 2):

Some of the Indiana Jones sets had some simple heavy weapon builds in them.

Set# 7625 had a belt fed/ammo-box mount style machine gun:

[image]

Set# 7626 had a RPG:

[image]